# Test Load Balancing in JMeter

Tags: testing, kubernetes, service, jmeter, load-balancing

I have a prototype service in a Kubernetes environment defined as LoadBalancer and this service points to 5 pods to perform Load Balancing. The service has also an external IP in order to be contacted outside of the cluster.
How can I build a Jmeter load test to check if Load Balancing is correctly performed? I think I have to execute more parallel requests to overload the server, but I don't know how to achieve this exactly.

NOTE: my application prototype sleeps for 1 second and returns in the response the pod name that is taking charge of that request, so I know what pod has been chosen by the LoadBalancer service.

Answer (score 0):

The process of identifying the first bottleneck is called [Stress Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_testing_(software)) and yes, you need to start with 1 thread (virtual user) and increase the load until response time starts exceeding acceptable threshold or errors start occurring (whatever comes the first)

If you need to check load balancing capabilities, i.e. your request should return the relevant pod ID - you can use [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) to extract the pod ID from the response and amend [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler label with what you get from the response, the code would be something like:

```
prev.setSampleLabel(prev.getSampleLabel() + ' - ' + prev.getResponseDataAsString())
```

Demo:

[image]

In the above example `prev` stands for the previous [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html), see the JavaDoc for all available functions/properties and [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) article for more information on this and other [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) shorthands exposed to [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)